# View to Bitmap not working using Canvas Draw method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I read a lot articles about how to turn view into bitmap, most of them suggest using a canvas draw method, but in my attempt, it return a transparent bitmap only, I am sure the view is proper, since I tried display it by add it in a view. I am also sure that the view is associated with a proper width and height, the following code is the conversion. This problem is annoying me for a week. please help me.

```
      val widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(layoutWidthDp,View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
      val heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(layoutHeightDp, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
      tableLayout.measure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec)
      tableLayout.layout(0, 0, tableLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), tableLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
      var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tableLayout.width, tableLayout.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
      val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
      tableLayout.draw(canvas)

      previewBitmap = bitmap
      previewIV = findViewById(R.id.finalLayoutPreviewIV)
      previewIV?.setImageBitmap(previewBitmap)
```

my target view is a view that not display. I don't isn't it relative to the problem, I put the creation process in the following.

```
val tableLayout = TableLayout(this)
        tableLayout.setLayoutParams(  TableLayout.LayoutParams(layoutWidthDp,layoutHeightDp))
        tableLayout.removeAllViews()
        Log.d("", tableLayout.layoutParams.toString())
        val padding = convertMMToDp(5F,resources).toInt()
        val widthDp = convertMMToDp(photoSizeWidth.toFloat(),resources).toInt()
        val heightDp = convertMMToDp(photoSizeHeight.toFloat(),resources).toInt()
        val colAmount = layoutWidthDp/ (widthDp+padding*2)
        val rowAmount = layoutHeightDp/ (heightDp+padding*2)
  
        for (i in 1..rowAmount){
            val tableRow = TableRow(this)
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
            )
            for (j in 1..colAmount){
                val layout = RelativeLayout(applicationContext)
                val photoItemVI = ImageView(applicationContext)
                if (photoPrototype.type?.background == "#FFFFFF") {
                    layout.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.color_light_white))
                }
                layout.addView(photoItemVI)
                photoItemVI.post(Runnable {

                    val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        widthDp, heightDp
                    )
                    params.setMargins(padding)
                    photoItemVI.setLayoutParams(params)
                    photoItemVI.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(photoPrototype.type?.background))
                    photoItemVI.setImageURI(photoPrototype.photo_without_background)
                    photoItemVI.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
                    photoItemVI.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
                    layout.updateViewLayout(photoItemVI, params);
                })
                tableRow.addView(layout)
            }
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `drawColor` method of the `Canvas` class which is supposed to draw a color to the canvas size specified to the `Bitmap` in `createBitmap`

This is essentially similar to taking a screenshot and I achieved it like so, notice the `drawColor` and the `inputBackground` takes in a color that changes based on theme of the device and will serve as the background for the `Canvas`

```
 public static Bitmap takeScreenshot(View rootView) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getWidth(), rootView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(ContextCompat.getColor(rootView.getContext(), R.color.inputBackground));
        rootView.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: thx for your quick response, I try adding the drawColor method but it only output the color I provided. it occurs to me that any change in the tablelayout is able to  draw in the canvas (like background color). My problem is those items inside the tableLayout not draw to the canvas.